# Why i am not able to submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on payment gateway, in that when i try to submit form with jquery it doesn't submit the form `$('#checkout_form').submit();` here is my whole code for that

```js
braintree.client.create({
            authorization: 'sandbox_g42y39zw_348pk9cgf3bgyw2b'
        }, function (err, clientInstance) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }

            braintree.hostedFields.create({
                client: clientInstance,
                styles: {
                    'input': {
                        'font-size': '14px',
                        'font-family': 'helvetica, tahoma, calibri, sans-serif',
                        'color': '#3a3a3a'
                    },
                    ':focus': {
                        'color': 'black'
                    }
                },
                fields: {
                    number: {
                        selector: '#card-number',
                        placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'
                    },
                    cvv: {
                        selector: '#cvv',
                        placeholder: '123'
                    },
                    expirationMonth: {
                        selector: '#expiration-month',
                        placeholder: 'MM'
                    },
                    expirationYear: {
                        selector: '#expiration-year',
                        placeholder: 'YY'
                    },
                    postalCode: {
                        selector: '#postal-code',
                        placeholder: '90210'
                    }
                }
            }, function (err, hostedFieldsInstance) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }

                hostedFieldsInstance.on('validityChange', function (event) {
                    var field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];

                    if (field.isValid) {
                        if (event.emittedBy === 'expirationMonth' || event.emittedBy === 'expirationYear') {
                            if (!event.fields.expirationMonth.isValid || !event.fields.expirationYear.isValid) {
                                return;
                            }
                        } else if (event.emittedBy === 'number') {
                            $('#card-number').next('span').text('');
                        }

                        // Remove any previously applied error or warning classes
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-warning');
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
                        // Apply styling for a valid field
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
                    } else if (field.isPotentiallyValid) {
                        // Remove styling  from potentially valid fields
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-warning');
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
                        if (event.emittedBy === 'number') {
                            $('#card-number').next('span').text('');
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Add styling to invalid fields
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-warning');
                        // Add helper text for an invalid card number
                        if (event.emittedBy === 'number') {
                            $('#card-number').next('span').text('Looks like this card number has an error.');
                        }
                    }
                });

                hostedFieldsInstance.on('cardTypeChange', function (event) {
                    // Handle a field's change, such as a change in validity or credit card type
                    if (event.cards.length === 1) {
                        $('#card-type').text(event.cards[0].niceType);
                    } else {
                        $('#card-type').text('Card');
                    }
                });



  $('.panel-body').submit(function (event) {
      if($('#nonce').val() == '') {
   event.preventDefault();
   hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (err, payload) {
       if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return false;
       }
       $('#nonce').val(payload.nonce);
       $('#checkout_form').submit();
       return true;
   });
      } else {
   return true;
      }
  });
            });
        });
```

```css
body {
     background-color: #fff;
 }

 .panel {
     width: 80%;
     margin: 2em auto;
 }

 .bootstrap-basic {
     background: white;
 }

 .panel-body {
     width: 90%;
     margin: 2em auto;
 }

 .helper-text {
     color: #8A6D3B;
     font-size: 12px;
     margin-top: 5px;
     height: 12px;
     display: block;
 }

 /* Braintree Hosted Fields styling classes*/
 .braintree-hosted-fields-focused { 
     border: 1px solid #0275d8;
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
 }

 .braintree-hosted-fields-focused.focused-invalid {
     border: 1px solid #ebcccc;
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(100,100,0,.6);
 }

 @media (max-width: 670px) {
     .btn {
  white-space: normal;
     }
 }
```

```html
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.36.0/js/client.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.36.0/js/hosted-fields.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="panel panel-default bootstrap-basic">
     <div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Enter Card Details</h3>
     </div>
     <form class="panel-body" action="checkout.php" method="post" id="checkout_form">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
   <label class="control-label">Card Number</label>
   <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
   <div class="form-control" id="card-number"></div>
   <span class="helper-text"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
       <label class="control-label col-xs-12">Expiration Date</label>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
    <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
    <div class="form-control" id="expiration-month"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
    <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
    <div class="form-control" id="expiration-year"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
   <label class="control-label">Security Code</label>
   <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
   <div class="form-control" id="cvv"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
   <label class="control-label">Zipcode</label>
   <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
   <div class="form-control" id="postal-code"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" id="nonce">
  <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg center-block">Pay with <span id="card-type">Card</span></button>
     </form>
 </div>
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue ?

Comment: You mention : event.preventDefault(); in side $('.panel-body').submit()... befor the form submition... this statement prevent submition

Comment: Then can you please tell me how can we submit it, because i need to wait before the value comes

Comment: Add event.preventDefault(); at bottom (after tokenize())

Comment: if i used it bottom then it also it is not submitting the form